# unknown property attribute 'atomic'

Tags: ios, xcode, fmdb

When i use FMDB test demo in xcode4.2, everything is good. But when I run the demo in xcode 3.2.6, it gives the error:"unknown property attribute 'atomic'"

```
        __unsafe_unretained id _delegate;

    NSUInteger          _maximumNumberOfDatabasesToCreate;
}

@property (atomic, retain) NSString *path;
@property (atomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (atomic, assign) NSUInteger maximumNumberOfDatabasesToCreate;
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember "atomic" attribute supported only by clang. When using gcc every property not declared as "nonatomic" is "atomic" by default.

Comment: Hi ,I have not seen this property as keywords also. But why this demo run well in my xcode4.2 ? My ios sdk is 5.0.

Comment: Xcode 4.x using clang compiler, while 3.x primary using gcc compiler. That simple. You can try to change compiler in Project Settings. Unfortunately I have no Xcode 3.x installed, so can't provide screenshot for you, sorry. 

You can try to remove all occurrences of "atomic" from code and compile project with Xcode 3.x

Answer (score 0):

`atomic` and `__unsafe_unretained` were introduced with LLVM 3.0. If you are using Xcode 3.2.6, you are using an older version of the compiler that does not support those keywords.

You can safely remove the `atomic` keyword, since a property is atomic by default; and also remove  `__unsafe_unretained`, since approximately it is equivalent to `assign` in a property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Clang's preprocessor macros](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features) to determine whether `atomic` is available in your compiler.  If the `atomic` keyword is not supported, it should be safe to omit it, since atomic is the implicit behavior anyway.

```
#if __has_feature(objc_atomic)
@property (atomic, retain) NSString *path;
@property (atomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (atomic, assign) NSUInteger maximumNumberOfDatabasesToCreate;
#else
@property (retain) NSString *path;
@property (assign) id delegate;
@property (assign) NSUInteger maximumNumberOfDatabasesToCreate;
#endif
```